# My windows partition is Fubar, how can I at least reclaim that HDD space for my ubuntu filesystem

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

My computer bluescreened whilst in windows. after some work and boot from an ubuntu flash drive, I was able to re-install Grub 2 and can boot into my linux partition,

after a failed attempt to restore the MBR for the windows partition, the partition no longer even identifies. I've tried recovering, and gpart is unable to recover any data.

My windows partition is hosed, I've come to piece with that. I'm here because the windows partition accounts for 80% of my HDD... So how do I get access to that sweet storage space for the OS that still works?

Answer (score 0):

Install and run gparted, delete the windows partition, then just resize the ubuntu partiton to take over that space.